# NativeScript, In ListView, ItemTap event is not working

Tags: nativescript

In `ListView`, `ItemTap` event is not working.

```
<ListView items="{{ menu }}" row="1" itemTap="listViewItemTap" >
      <ListView.itemTemplate>
        <GridLayout columns="auto, *">
          <Image src="{{ imageURL }}" row="0" cssClass="icon"/>
          <StackLayout col="1">
            <Label text="{{ title }}"  cssClass="name"/>
            <Label text="{{ subtitle }}" cssClass="location"/>
          </StackLayout>
        </GridLayout>
      </ListView.itemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Hello - please provide your code-behind where you have exported the itemTap function. In the issue system I have posted a simple example for that function. https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/1995

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you make sure you have the `listViewItemTap` exported in your code.
I have tried the following and seems to work OK:

XML:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo">
  <ListView items="{{ menu }}" row="1" itemTap="listViewItemTap" >
    <ListView.itemTemplate>
      <GridLayout columns="auto, *">
        <Image src="{{ imageURL }}" row="0" cssClass="icon"/>
        <StackLayout col="1">
          <Label text="{{ title }}"  cssClass="name"/>
          <Label text="{{ subtitle }}" cssClass="location"/>
        </StackLayout>
      </GridLayout>
    </ListView.itemTemplate> 
  </ListView>
</Page>
```

JS:

```
exports.onNavigatingTo = function(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = {
        menu:[
            { imageUrl: "", title: "title 1", subtitle: "subtitle 1"},
            { imageUrl: "", title: "title 2", subtitle: "subtitle 2"},
            { imageUrl: "", title: "title 3", subtitle: "subtitle 3"},
            { imageUrl: "", title: "title 4", subtitle: "subtitle 4"},
        ]
    }
}

exports.listViewItemTap = function() {
    console.log("Item tapped!");
}
```

Also one thing to look for:

- If you **are not** using binding for the `itemTap` event(as in the XML you posted) - you should provide the event handler in the code-behind of the page.
- If you **are** using binding (`itemTap="{{ listViewItemTap }}"`) you should provide the event handler in your bindingContext object.

Comment: Thanks. 
This sample is working.  
On thing i want to remember, I have integrated pulltorefresh plugin in our project so that i want to check why it was not working?.